# Determine the real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $1$, $\frac1{1+\omega}$ and $\frac1{1+\omega^*}$ are zeroes of the polynomial $p(z)=z^3+az^2+bz+c$

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers, roots

I am stuck on this question:

[image]

> Let $1$, $\omega$ and $\omega^*$ be the cube root of unity.
>
> a. Show that $\dfrac1{1+\omega}=-\omega$ and $\dfrac1{1+\omega^*}=-\omega^*$.
>
> b. Determine the real numbers $a$, $b$, $c$ such that $1$, $\dfrac1{1+\omega}$ and $\dfrac1{1+\omega^*}$ are zeroes of the polynomial $p(z)=z^3+az^2+bz+c$.
>
> c. Hence, find $p(\omega)$ and $p(\omega^*)$.

So I was able to do part **a** by finding the roots in Cartesian forms, but I am not sure how to approach part **b**.

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We use the familiar fact that
$$
(x - \alpha) (x - \beta) = x^{2} - (\alpha + \beta) x + \alpha \beta.
$$

For part **a**, note that $1, \omega, \omega^{*}$ are the three distinct roots of
$$
x^{3} - 1 = (x -1) (x^{2} + x + 1).
$$
Therefore $\omega, \omega^{*}$ are the roots of $x^{2} + x + 1$. Hence their product equals the constant coefficient $1$, so that
$$
\omega^{*} = \omega^{-1},
$$
and their sum equals $-1$, that is, the negative of the coefficient of $x$, so that
$$
\omega + \omega^{*} = -1,
$$
and your formulas follow.

For **b**, you may note that because of the above formulas,
$$
\frac{1}{1 + \omega} = - \omega,
\quad\text{and}\quad
\frac{1}{1 + \omega^{*}} = - \omega^{*}
$$
are the roots of $x^{2} - x + 1$, and so 
$$
1, - \omega, - \omega^{*}
$$
will be the roots of
$$
(x - 1) (x^{2} - x + 1)
=
x^{3} - 2 x^{2} + 2 x - 1.
$$

Answer (score 5):

For those three numbers to be roots of the cubic equation means that if you set $z$ equal to any one of them, then the cubic is zero. Therefore you can write $$z^3+az^2+bz+c\equiv(z-1)\left(z-\frac1{1+\omega}\right)\left(z-\frac1{1+\omega^*}\right)$$ To determine $a,b,c$, simply multiply this out and equate the coefficients of different powers of $z$.